# Is it possible with Java 8 to create a list or any other data structure grouped, ordered and counted in one-step?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a file with this structure:

```
a, City1, 2013-09-05 14:08:15
b, City2, 2015-10-08 16:10:15
c, City2, 2010-09-05 14:08:15
d, City1, 2011-09-05 14:08:15
```

It's comma separated values and lines separated with end of line character.

I need to create a data structure in Java 8 where I have the rows grouped by city and within each such group sort by date in ascending order and counting the amount of rows within each group.

I tried:

1. Create a `List<Row>` from the file
2. Create a `Map<String, List<Row>>` which is grouped by city and sort by date withing each group
3. Create a `Map<String, Long>` for grouping by city and amount of rows

This is code I've tried:

```
public PhotoResponse processFile()  {
    //read each line of the file and create a new object PhotoIn for each one
    List<PhotoIn> lista = null;
    try {
        lista = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(photo -> new PhotoIn(photo[0].substring(0, photo[0].lastIndexOf(".")), photo[0].substring(photo[0].lastIndexOf(".") + 1 ), photo[1].trim(), parseDate(photo[2]), index++))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return generateOutput(lista); 
}


private PhotoResponse generateOutput(List<PhotoIn> photos) {

    //Grouping photos by city
    Map<String, List<PhotoIn>> photosByCity = photos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PhotoIn::getCity));

    //Sorting photos by date into each city
    photosByCity.values().forEach(list -> list.sort(Comparator.comparing(PhotoIn::getDate)));

    //Grouping photos by city and amount
    Map<String, Long> numeroPorCiudades = photos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PhotoIn::getCity, Collectors.counting()));

    List<PhotoOut> photoOutList = new ArrayList<PhotoOut>();

    photosByCity.forEach((key, list) -> {
        String digits = Integer.toString(Long.toString(numeroPorCiudades.get(key)).length());
        counter = 1;
        list.forEach(photoIn -> {
            photoOutList.add(new PhotoOut(photoIn.getName() + "." + photoIn.getExtension(), key + String.format("%0" + digits + "d", counter++) + "." + photoIn.getExtension(), photoIn.getIndex()));
        });
    });
    return sortOutput(photoOutList);
}
```

I'm solving the problem but I'm looking for a better and more efficient way to do it with Java 8. **Is it possible to make those 3 steps in just one step?**. What I need is group all that information in just one data structure.

Comment: share your solution.

Comment: What have you got so far? The solution is presumably going to be dominated by I/O. Easy to understand is probably better the clever. Going for a one liner, presumably a `Collectors.groupingBy` collector using a `TreeSet` collector. The number of rows is just calling `size` on the `Set<Row>`s.

Comment: Please don't delete your posted code as you may invalidate existing answers by doing this.

Comment: By the way, you'll have a SPACE at the front of your city and date strings. Split on `, ` (COMMA + SPACE) not `,`. Or call [`String::strip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) afterwards.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks. It was just a preview of the code at the moment. I had already made some corrections.

Answer (score 2):

With that model:

```
class Model {
  private String title;
  private String city;
  private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

It can be done like this:

```
List<Model> list = getFromFile();

Comparator<Model> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Model::getDate);

//grouping the list by City with lists sorted by date
Map<String, List<Model>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy( //grouping the list by City with lists 
            m -> m.getCity(),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), l->{
              l.sort(comparator);
              return l;
            })
        )
    );

//getting another map with counts
Map<String, Object> countMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().size()));
```

Comment: @icj03 Just tested it, everything is working fine for me, I don't even have any warnings from my Intellij idea. I don't know, maybe some jvm-specific issue. I'm using 1.8.0_211

Comment: I actually hate the old Date API, but it's not the question here. Edited the answer to LocalDateTime, it hasn't affected the algorithm at all.

Comment: you get exactly the same result if you sort first then just group without `Collectors::collectingAndThen`